# Script or Program to discover hosts on network

Tags: bash, scripting, python

***Explanation:***

I need a script or program to discover devices on my network. I was thinking maybe doing the scan with `nmap` and I need to display just the name of device, what it is, and also the ip address/mac address of the device as well. I would like to do the scan in the background and only display the desired information in the form of a list I guess.

***Example:***

after script / program runs:

-**There are 2 hosts up**

- **Host 1:** Lenovo-PC | 192.168.1.86 | 0A:65:3F:2B:F1 | Windows
- **Host 2:** LG-3444 | 192.168.1.89 | A9:B2:C3:D4:E5 | LG Electronics

ect... you get the point.

PS: BTW, these are examples not real IP's.

***Overview***

So I want to scan my network for devices / hosts and display important info about each one in a list (using bash script, python, or anything that can achieve this).

Comment: `nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24 | grep report; arp -an` will give you a good place to start.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Thanks for the tip, but It's not quite what I was looking for. I don't want to just run a scan, I want to copy certain parts from the scan and paste them in a certain order and in a list if there are more than 1 device.

Comment: `nmap -oG - 192.168.1.0/24` gives output that you can `grep`. The `-oX` option provides it as XML, so you can use XPath on it.

Comment: @roaima  you say "output that you can grep" ...Could you please provide an example to clarify? I'm just getting  into scripting so I'm a little new to grep

Comment: @iamt00t run the example I've given

Answer (score 0):

This is an example in perl. The code run `nmap` with XML output format and then parse the output using Nmap::Parser library. You need to provide network mask as an argument. So if you save this skript to the `explore.pl` file, you can run it as

```
explore.pl 192.168.1.0/24
```

You need to run this script as [root if you want to display MAC addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14165492/2956276).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Nmap::Parser;

sub safeGet($){
  defined $_[0] ? $_[0] : "unknown";
}

my $nmOutput=`/usr/bin/nmap -oX - -A @ARGV`;

my $np = new Nmap::Parser;
$np->parse($nmOutput);

my $cnt=0;
for my $host ($np->all_hosts()){
  $cnt++;

  my $hostName = 'unknown';
  if(@{$host->{hostnames}} > 0){ # $host->hostname returns "0" when no hostname was found.
    $hostName = $host->hostname;
  }
  print "Host $cnt: $hostName|"
    . safeGet($host->addr) ."|"
    . safeGet($host->mac_addr)."|"
    . safeGet($host->os_sig->name)."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```bash
nmap -sn 10.0.1.0/24 | grep report | cut -f5,6 -d' ' | \
    while read line
    do
        echo -n "$line "
        arp -an $(echo $line | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}') | cut -f4 -d' '
    done
```